# pushing view controller inside a tab bar from app delegate, after a notification

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

i have an app with tab bar and a navigation controller inside every tab.
i have set a notification that when it lunches the user can get lunch the app by pressing the action on the alert.

i want to redirect the user to one of the views inside one of the controllers.

i have tried this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    NSArray *data = [notif.userInfo objectForKey:@"todoDate"];
    NSInteger ind = [[data objectAtIndex:2] integerValue];

    QuickViewController *detailViewController ;
    detailViewController = [[QuickViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuickViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.title = @"Edit";
    detailViewController.personName = [data objectAtIndex:0];
    detailViewController.DelitionDate=[data objectAtIndex:1];
    detailViewController.personCategory=@"NO Category";
    detailViewController.personID = ind r ;

    rootControler.selectedIndex = 1;
    [rootControler.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

but nothing is happening (no crashing) except of the :rootControler.selectedIndex = 1;

when i tried :
presentModalViewController

i got the view perfectly but without the navigation controller.

thanks
shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're pushing `detailViewController` when you really want to push a `UINavigationController` with `detailViewController` as its root view. Try something like this:

```
QuickViewController *detailViewController ;

detailViewController =
[[QuickViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuickViewController"
                                      bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController =
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController];

[detailViewController release];

...

[rootControler.tabBarController.selectedViewController.navigationController 
pushViewController:navigationController animated:YES]
```

Comment: thanks jeff

now its working, only had to change the last command to:
[rootControler presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];

good day

Comment: No problem. Feel free to click the green checkmark to mark this answer as accepted; it'll help your chances of getting future questions answered.